# Method on button

Tags: javascript, methods, hyperlink

i am trying to call a method when i press a link and the method itself has a parameter,the problem is that the method is called regardless if i press the link or not

Here is the code:

```
  <Link onClick={this.goToShow(show1.name)}>{show1.name}</Link>
```

and the function

```
goToShow(param){
        axiosInstance.post("/user/search",param).then(
            res=>{
                localStorage.setItem("SEARCHED_CHARACTER",res.data.caracterDTO)
            }
        )
        this.props.history.push("/user/searchedCharacter")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling that function instead of passing the function to onClick, change that line to this:

```
  <Link onClick={() => this.goToShow(show1.name)}>{show1.name}</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

- i think that if you used a js with a link the code won't take a chance even to be executed because the link will lead the user to the page anyway i think that using js events as attributes it's not a good structure for your code it's better to handle all events from js
- you can try the following

```
<link href="#" id="mylink">click here</link>
```

```
var link = document.getElementById("mylink")
link.addEventListener("click", function() { 

  goToShow(param){
        axiosInstance.post("/user/search",param).then(
            res=>{
                localStorage.setItem("SEARCHED_CHARACTER",res.data.caracterDTO)
            }
        )
        this.props.history.push("/user/searchedCharacter")
    }

});
```